Added a person to a joint account
If a account has been open between husband and wife and another party gets added by consent of one and that party died and the added person empties the account,
can that party remove all money to a CD?
Is it stealing
How do I report that my account is empty with person being on account with stipulation of taking advantage and stealing from me

If they were given full access to the account they can withdraw money from the account, as far as the bank is concerned. Whether it's legally actionable depends on exactly what paperwork is in place; you need to talk to a lawyer about that.

I’m voting to close this question because the answer will depend on exactly who signed which paper saying what as and you will probably need a local lawyer to straighten it out. But odds are you're not going to like their answer. If somebody has permission to access the account, they have permission. If they then Grant access to someone else, that may be a violation of the banks terms of service, but that seems unlikely to rescue you from the results of their decision.

You will have to talk to a lawyer about this.
From the bank's point of view, if a signatory is added to an account then that person can withdraw from the account under the same conditions as the other signatories. The bank has done everything it needs (assuming the signatory was added legitimately and the bank shouldn't have got your permission to do it).
But just because someone is authorized to take money from an account doesn't mean it is legally theirs. But that question is one of law, not finance and we cannot answer it.
